# Chrome displaying tooltip behind link

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Developing a plugin for Chrome, I've used `data-tooltip` for links which require a tooltip. Until 2-3 days ago, everything seemed to be working fine.

Today I've discovered that the tooltip for links inside a modal display behind the modal. Nothing has changed in my code. I even tested with older versions of my app ant it still displays the tooltips behind the modal.

My guess is that Chrome has changed the way it views tooltips. Any idea what I can do to fix it?

Example of tooltip usage:

```
<div class="choose-platform" data-tooltip="GoogleDrive">
                    ...
</div>
```

Screenshot of the error I'm facing

[image: On hover of Google Drive Icon, the tooltip appears behind modal]

On hover of Google Drive Icon, the tooltip appears behind modal

Comment: Which version of Google-chorome you have used?

Comment: @MaldeChavda The latest one: 33.0.1750.154 m

Comment: try to `z-index` on tooltip content class

Answer (score 0):

It seems like tooltip is appended in body. Try giving higher `z-index` than modal box

Comment: My tooltip is not a specific HTML element. It's an attribute assigned to the div. On hover of this div, tooltip is displayed. I don't think I can style a `data-*` attribute of an HTML element.

Comment: @Newtt are you using any plugin, then these plugins automatically appen a tooltip div to html or to element. In your case it seem to appended to body, so please try increasing z-index of tooltip div in respective css

Comment: I'm developing a plugin myself. The tooltip doesn't seem to be giving an error on normal links. Only on the modal. The modal z-index by default is 1350 and I made the link's Z-index to 2000 but it made no difference to the appearance of the tooltip.

Comment: @Newtt give higher z-index to tooltip class not to link

Comment: so in this example, you mean to class 'choose-platform', right?

Comment: @Newtt I think you are using class 'choose-platform' for div which toggles the tooltip. You need to use class of tooltip itself, i.e. class which give tooltip its color & styling. If you still dont eot it, add jsfiddle of your code so I can check it.